# Include Java Hex Editor in Eclipse PDE Manifest

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to use the Java Hex editor plugin from Eclipse Marketplace in my Eclipse PDE plugin. I want the Java Hex Editor to be installed when my plugin is installed, so that the Hex Editor may be used to display image data in hex form. When I try to include the plugin by using the tag in the plugin.xml, the plugin.xml file states that this 3rd party plugin must be included in the Plugin MANIFEST file instead. I do not want to use features, if it is possible to avoid them, as my project is set up following the standard PDE structure. **How do I include the Java hex editor in my plugin using the plugin MANIFEST?**

**Current Manifest:**
[image]

**Java Hex Editor Installation Details:**

[image]

Comment: You can't do this just using the MANIFEST.MF. You do need to use features which PDE understands fine.

Comment: So how would I add a feature to the PDE plugin that I have developed so that I can include the Java Hex editor plugin?

Comment: You create a separate Feature project and add the plug-ins to the feature.

Comment: Both the plugin I created as well as the Java Hex editor plugin?

Comment: yes, both plug-ins

Comment: Will I be able to call the Java Hex Editor from my plugin still? I want to be able to open the editor for a specific file when it is produced by my main plugin